# R data.table delete the columns that end in "_nd"

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable in R

I'd like to delete the columns that end in **"_nd"**.

**My dt:**

[image]

**I'd like**

[image]

**I want the opposite of this script**

```
dt[,.SD, .SDcols = patterns("_nd")]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be to grep within `J`.

```
dt[,names(dt)[grep("_nd",names(dt))] := NULL]
```

The benefit of this approach is that it removes by reference.

Answer (score 4):

I'll do :

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(var1 = 1:10, var1_n = 1:10, var2_n = 1:10)
dt
#     var1 var1_n var2_n
#    <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1:     1      1      1
# 2:     2      2      2
# 3:     3      3      3
# 4:     4      4      4
# 5:     5      5      5
# 6:     6      6      6
# 7:     7      7      7
# 8:     8      8      8
# 9:     9      9      9
# 10:    10     10     10

to_rm <- grep("_n$", names(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[, (to_rm) := NULL]
dt
#     var1
#    <int>
# 1:     1
# 2:     2
# 3:     3
# 4:     4
# 5:     5
# 6:     6
# 7:     7
# 8:     8
# 9:     9
# 10:    10
```

or maybe simpler:

```
dt <- data.table(var1 = 1:10, var1_n = 1:10, var2_n = 1:10)
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = grep("_n$", names(dt), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)]
```

This will also work:

```
dt <- data.table(var1 = 1:10, var1_n = 1:10, var2_n = 1:10)
to_keep <- grep("_n$", names(dt), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
dt[, ..to_keep]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in base-R

```
mydata[-grep("_nd$",names(mydata))]
```

output:

```
  dtniass sex country age
1 2020-02   M       J  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set`. Just pass as character vector of the columns you want to delete.

```
library(data.table)

set(dt, j=grep("_nd$", names(dt), value=TRUE), value=NULL)
```